# Performing an inner join with double id'ies

Tags: sql, join

I have a table including `creatorID` and `modifierID`. By using this id's I would like to take peoples names with one query. How can I do that? I mean how to do the following with one query:

```
selact n.name
from Names n
  inner join table1 t on n.userID=t.creatorID

selact n.name
from Names n
  inner join table1 t on n.userID=t.modifierID
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output, along with the tables you are querying?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be difficult:

```
SELECT
    table1.*
    ,CName.Name AS Creator
    ,MName.Name AS Modifier
FROM
    table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Names CName ON table1.CreatorID = CName.UserID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Names MName ON ModifierID = MName.UserID
```

I have taken left outer joins assuming that the CreatorID and ModifierID columns can be null. If you are looking for something else, let me know.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns NULL where no matching row in right side table. Has nothing to do with if CreatorID and ModifierID are nullable or not.

Comment: 0 means there is no modifier. i am now trying Adish's solution.

Comment: Yes Adish solved my problem. and how to replace null results with ""

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to `OR` the current conditions:

```
select n.name
from Names n
  inner join table1 t on n.userID = t.creatorID
                      OR n.userID = t.modifierID
```

Can also be written as `IN`:

```
select n.name
from Names n
  inner join table1 t on n.userID IN (t.creatorID, t.modifierID)
```

Or, perhaps, you mean `AND` instead?

Comment: does this querry return only one name? i just need the name of creator and modifier. i dont want to see id'ies on my datagridview. i mean i just want to replace id's with real human names. but i want to take them with one querry. ı think your querry returns only one name.

Comment: Hard to tell how many names it returns. (Depends on the table data...) If you add sample data and expected result it would be easier to assist.